# MapKit .. Direction ... wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mapkit, directions

I'm in Aqaba, Jordan and my pin is set to Petra, what I wanted to do is set the direction from "my location" in Aqaba, Jordan (Or any place in Jordan) to Petra also in Jordan with a coordinates 30.322098,35.451790 .. it's not working.

(Direction is a button that goes to Map Application)

On the iPhone, it gives me this error when I choose "Current location": Direction No Available.

On the iPhone, it "Dropped Pin" it chooses a different pin that I didn't set in Jordan.

On a simulator, it gives me this error when I click on Directions "Current Location Not Available"

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CHDIRNSObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize CHDirectionMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    MKCoordinateRegion CHRegion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
    CHRegion.center.latitude = 30.322098;
    CHRegion.center.longitude = 35.451790;
    CHRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 5.00f;
    CHRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 5.00f;
    [CHDirectionMapView setRegion:CHRegion animated:YES];

    CHDIRNSObject *CHann = [[CHDIRNSObject alloc] init];
    CHann.title = @"Petra";
    CHann.subtitle = @"Petra";
    CHann.coordinate = CHRegion.center;
    [CHDirectionMapView addAnnotation:CHann];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)CHDirection:(id)sender {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {

        case 0:
            CHDirectionMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            CHDirectionMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

-(IBAction)CHGetLocation:(id)sender {
    CHDirectionMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
-(IBAction)CHDirect:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=30.322098,35.451790";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

}
@end
```

Help :)

Comment: If I ask Apple maps for directions between Aqaba and Petra it tells me that no directions are available, so I guess Apple doesn't know how to get between those two places.

Comment: You made me ... lost :)
Can you please explain more?

Comment: Okay, I'll try google Maps instead, I don't know its code, shall I change this:

-(IBAction)CHDirect:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=30.322098,35.451790";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

To what exactly?